# hover popup not working in my main code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on the mouse hover pop up....
it works fine when i execute separately....
but it does not work out fine when i combine it with my whole code...
i even included the jquery libraries....
how to fix it....
providing my code below....

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/X9a6j/1/embedded/result/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var tooltipTimeout;

            $("#someelem").hover(function()
                                {tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(showTooltip, 2000);}, 
                                hideTooltip);

            function showTooltip()
                {
                var tooltip = $("<div id='tooltip' class='tooltip'>I'm the tooltip!</div>");
                tooltip.appendTo($("#someelem"));
                }

            function hideTooltip()
                {
                clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
                $("#tooltip").fadeOut().remove();
                }
            </script>


            <style>

                #someelem
    {
    cursor: pointer;
    }

.tooltip
    {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(130, 150, 200);
    padding: 5px;
    }


<span id="someelem">Hover me for 2 seconds!</span>
```

Comment: in the jsfiddle - the js is raising an exception near the bottom as there isnt a tabSelector element defined. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null @ 2027`

Comment: thanks for your reply how to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the DOM elements are loading before the Javascript?

Try wrapping the code block you posted in a ready function

```
$(function(){
    // code you posted
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#someelem").hover(function() {
        console.log("In hover");
                tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(showTooltip, 2000);

            },
            hideTooltip);
     });
```

With the help of `$(document).ready(function(){ });` It is going into hover function.
and it is printing "In hover" in console log.